# Should I use a semicolon or a colon in the following case?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

> I didn't like Anna calling Tom a bad person. However, most of the boys
>   in our class shared her view;/: Tom often bullied others, always
>   mocked the weak, and stole stuff from time to time.

Should that be a colon or a semicolon? And why?

Comment: I'd use a colon, because the part after adds information and explanation. See http://www2.le.ac.uk/offices/ld/resources/writing/grammar/grammar-guides/semicolon

Comment: A period would be easier on me. Any reader can still get the import. Why complicate? Strictly speaking, though, neither colon nor semi-colon would be appropriate here. Think why. :)

Comment: I'd use ", for"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at their respective definitions.

*colon*

> a punctuation mark (:) used to precede a list of items, a quotation, or an expansion or **explanation**.

*semicolon*

> a punctuation mark (;) indicating a pause, typically between two main clauses, that is more pronounced than that indicated by a comma.

Thus, we can see that in that case, you can technically use either a semicolon or a colon, because it is an **explanation** that **links together two main clauses**.

However, it may be better to use a colon because it is more accurate to call it an explanation rather than a related sentence.